# Remove indentation of cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

How can I remove the indent from the title cell of a column with conditional icons?

[image: padding]

If I remove the conditional icons, the padding dissappear:

[image: No padding]

Comment: I don't see any margin there, just the border of the active cell. Also it's not clear how it's related to conditional formatting. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I thinks it's quite clear in the screenshot, After adding the conditional icons, the text of the active cell has moved to the right. It has a padding to the left that I don't know how to remove.

Comment: Border is the black line around your cell, so your description is misleading. What you mean is "indent". Make sure you don't apply the conditional formatting to the title.

Comment: "Make sure you don't apply the conditional formatting to the title".. Thanks.. this was the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add this type of conditional formatting of a cell, content will be shifted to the right even if no data is available for getting any icon.

To get rid of it: make sure you apply conditional formatting only to the cells you really need the icon, and not for the header.

Comment: I've down voted this answer because, while applying this type of conditional formatting, contents never shifts to right !!.

Comment: @RajeshS this answer is accepted so IT SOLVES the problem of the OP. Try applying the conditional formatting (2nd example in your answer) to the header cell too.

Answer (score -2):

I think you were struggling with text alignment.

For the cell with the text "Diferencia" your alignment might have been improper. I've reproduced some of your data and applied the same conditional formatting to the data set, including the title cell.

I used Center Alignment for cells with numbers, Wrap Text, and I adjusted the Column Width for the title cell. As you can see in the picture below, there is no padding similar to what you observed.

However, since I was **unable to reproduce your original problem** (text having the indent), the adjustments I've applied are completely meaningless.

[image]